# Why do I turn into super Mario instead of fire Mario when I touch a fire flower AS SMALL Mario in Super Mario Bros 1?

Tags: super-mario-bros

When I was playing Super Mario Bros 1, I - as Super Mario - hit a block containing a fire flower. I then got hit by an enemy, changing me into small Mario, but the fire flower was still on-screen.

When I touched the fire flower as Small Mario, it just turned me into Super Mario instead of Fire Mario.

Why does this happen?

Comment: Meta post about this question: [Why is this question about a game mechanic off topic?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15671/4797)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

For a technical explanation, [if we look at the disassembled code for Super Mario Bros](https://gist.github.com/1wErt3r/4048722), we can see that the routine for collecting fire flowers and super mushrooms is exactly the same.

```
HandlePowerUpCollision:
  jsr EraseEnemyObject    ;erase the power-up object
  lda #$06
  jsr SetupFloateyNumber  ;award 1000 points to player by default
  lda #Sfx_PowerUpGrab
  sta Square2SoundQueue   ;play the power-up sound
  lda PowerUpType         ;check power-up type
  cmp #$02
  bcc Shroom_Flower_PUp   ;if mushroom or fire flower, branch
  cmp #$03
  beq SetFor1Up           ;if 1-up mushroom, branch
  lda #$23                ;otherwise set star mario invincibility
  sta StarInvincibleTimer ;timer, and load the star mario music
  lda #StarPowerMusic     ;into the area music queue, then leave
  sta AreaMusicQueue
  rts

Shroom_Flower_PUp:
  lda PlayerStatus    ;if player status = small, branch
  beq UpToSuper
  cmp #$01            ;if player status not super, leave
  bne NoPUp
  ldx ObjectOffset    ;get enemy offset, not necessary
  lda #$02            ;set player status to fiery
  sta PlayerStatus
  jsr GetPlayerColors ;run sub to change colors of player
  ldx ObjectOffset    ;get enemy offset again, and again not necessary
  lda #$0c            ;set value to be used by subroutine tree (fiery)
  jmp UpToFiery       ;jump to set values accordingly
```

I would say this is intended behavior. If you somehow could get a super mushroom onscreen while you were Super Mario, he would turn into Firey Mario. Most likely, the rationale is to save space on the ROM.

Answer (score -3):

Yes as the weakened Mario the game script only allows 1 stage progression from in level items so anything for small Mario(1 hit to kill) go to super mario(2 hit to kill), then only if the item is tir 3 fire flower will grant the special mario(3 hit to kill).

Answer (score -6):

I always saw it as a 3 stages of Mario

Mini - Big - Fire

And the powerups do not just do +1 to the stage counter. They just boost you up to the appropriate stage (if the stage is higher than the current.)

Like if you get a mushroom and already is on the Big stage, you will not go up to fire, you stay big.

So when you touch a fire flower, that you would be Mini or big it boosts you up to Fire stage. Its like if the mushroom is always included in the flower.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v2lVgHaRDf8 demonstrates that they are two separate flags, with hilarious results if you mess around with them.

Comment: The question is why does it _not_ work the way you've described.

Comment: How is this an up voted answer ? OP clearly states it did not work like this in his interaction. I am so confused by this site sometimes.